# Que metodo puedo utilizar para utilizar el valor seleccionado de un TableView y utilizarlo en una consulta

Tags: mysql, mvc, javafx, uitableview

mi proyecto lo corro en javaFX8, con dynamicreports 6.12.0 y mysql conector 8.0.2 y lo manejo en estructura MVC

Mi detalle esta en que en mi proyecto realizo una consulta cargando pedidos por medio de folios , realizo la consulta y me imprime el detalle del pedido en un primer TableView y al seleccionar un dato en este caso el código de articulo, deberá realizar una consulta que me muestre una estadística viniendo de una segunda consulta , la cual los resultados se deben mostrar en un segundo TableView y se deben ir actualizando cada que seleccione el siguiente articulo del detalle del pedido.

Adjunto mis clases

Clase EstadisticasController

```
import com.savadr.HerramientaFX8.Modelo.DBConector;
import com.savadr.HerramientaFX8.Modelo.Estadisticas;
import com.savadr.HerramientaFX8.Modelo.EstadisticasQuery;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import org.apache.poi.hsmf.datatypes.PropertyValue;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class EstadisticasController implements Initializable {

    private final Map<String, Integer> sucSav = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<String, Integer> sucAdr = new HashMap<>();
    @FXML
    private TableView tabEstadisticaArt;
    @FXML
    private TableView tabDetallePed;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn colArtClas;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn colArtCod;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn colArtDesc;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn colArtCant;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox cbxArticulo;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox cbxGrupo;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox cbxCantidad;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox cbxFol;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox cbbType;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox cbbSucursales;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtArticulo;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtGrupo;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtFolioPed;
    @FXML
    private Button btnConsultaPed;
    @FXML
    private Button btnLimpiar;
    @FXML
    private Button btnSalir;
    private Stage stage;
    private DBConector db;
    private EstadisticasQuery statisticsQuery;
    private MenuPrincipalController mpController;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        sucSav.put("Cordoba", 1);
        sucSav.put("Coatzacoalcos", 2);
        sucSav.put("Merida", 3);
        sucSav.put("Matriz", 4);
        sucSav.put("Tejeria", 5);
        sucSav.put("Tuxtla", 6);
        sucSav.put("Villahermosa", 7);

        sucAdr.put("Matriz", 1);
        sucAdr.put("Cuauhtemoc", 2);
        sucAdr.put("Xalapa", 3);

        cbxArticulo.setSelected(false);
        cbxArticulo.setOnAction(ev -> setCheckBoxState());

        cbxFol.setSelected(false);
        cbxFol.setOnAction(ev -> setCheckBoxState());

        btnSalir.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            Stage actualStage = (Stage) btnSalir.getScene().getWindow();
            actualStage.close();
            try {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/com/savadr/HerramientaFX8/Vista/MenuPrincipal.fxml"));
                Parent mpRoot = loader.load();
                Scene scene = new Scene(mpRoot);
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                stage.setScene(scene);
                com.savadr.HerramientaFX8.Controlador.MenuPrincipalController mpController = loader.getController();
                mpController.init(stage, null);
                stage.show();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        db = DBConector.getInstance();
        statisticsQuery = new EstadisticasQuery(db.getCon());
        //Columns for tabDetallePed
        colArtClas.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("artClas"));
        colArtClas.setCellFactory(forTableColumn(Pos.CENTER));
        colArtCod.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("artCod"));
        colArtCod.setCellFactory(forTableColumn(Pos.CENTER));
        colArtDesc.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("artDesc"));
        colArtDesc.setCellFactory(forTableColumn(Pos.CENTER));
        colArtCant.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("artCant"));
        colArtCant.setCellFactory(forTableColumn(Pos.CENTER));

        if(db != null && db.isConnectedSurtidora()){
            ObservableList<String> listSav = FXCollections.observableArrayList(sucSav.keySet());
            cbbSucursales.setItems(listSav);
        }else if(db != null && db.isConnectedAdrimar()){
            ObservableList<String> listAdr = FXCollections.observableArrayList(sucAdr.keySet());
            cbbSucursales.setItems(listAdr);
        }
        ObservableList<String> typeList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Cotizacion", "Orden de Compra", "Solicitud de Traspaso");
        cbbType.setItems(typeList);
    }
    void init(Stage stageSt, MenuPrincipalController aThis) {
        this.mpController = aThis;
        this.stage = stageSt;
    }
    public Stage getStage() {
        return stage;
    }
    public void setStage(Stage stage) {
        this.stage = stage;
    }
    public void setDBConector(DBConector db) {
        this.db = db;
    }
    private void showAlert(String title, String content) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle(title);
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText(content);
        alert.showAndWait();
    }
    @FXML
    private void showQuerys(ActionEvent e){
        String filterFol = txtFolioPed.getText();
        String filterArt = txtArticulo.getText();
        String filterGru = txtGrupo.getText();
        boolean cbxArtSelected = cbxArticulo.isSelected();
        boolean cbxGruSelected = cbxGrupo.isSelected();
        boolean cbxCantCeroSelected = cbxCantidad.isSelected();

        if(!cbxArticulo.isSelected() && !cbxFol.isSelected()){
            showAlert("Advertencia","Seleccione un metodo de busqueda");
        }else if(cbxArticulo.isSelected() && cbbSucursales.getSelectionModel().isEmpty()){
            showAlert("Advertencia","Seleccione una sucursal.");
        }else if(cbxFol.isSelected() && cbbType.getSelectionModel().isEmpty()){
            showAlert("Advertencia","Seleccione un de tipo folio.");
        }else{
            if(db.isConnectedSurtidora()){
                if(cbxFol.isSelected()){
                    String selectedFolType =(String) cbbType.getValue();
                    switch(selectedFolType){
                        case "Cotizacion":
                            ObservableList<Estadisticas> resClientSav = statisticsQuery.getClientOrder(filterFol);
                            tabDetallePed.setItems(resClientSav);
                            break;
                        case "Orden de Compra":
                            ObservableList<Estadisticas> resPurOrdSav = statisticsQuery.getPurchaseOrder(filterFol);
                            tabDetallePed.setItems(resPurOrdSav);
                            break;
                        case "Solicitud de Traspaso":
                            ObservableList<Estadisticas> resBranOrdSav = statisticsQuery.getBranchOrder(filterFol);
                            tabDetallePed.setItems(resBranOrdSav);
                            break;
                        default:
                            showAlert("Advertencia","No ha seleccionado ningun tipo");
                            break;
                    }
                }else{

                }
            }else if(db.isConnectedAdrimar()){
                if(cbxFol.isSelected()){
                    String selectedFolType =(String) cbbType.getValue();
                    switch(selectedFolType){
                        case "Cotizacion":
                            ObservableList<Estadisticas> resClientAdr = statisticsQuery.getClientOrder(filterFol);
                            tabDetallePed.setItems(resClientAdr);
                            break;
                        case "Orden de Compra":
                            ObservableList<Estadisticas> resPurOrdAdr = statisticsQuery.getPurchaseOrder(filterFol);
                            tabDetallePed.setItems(resPurOrdAdr);
                            break;
                        case "Solicitud de Traspaso":
                            ObservableList<Estadisticas> resBranOrdAdr = statisticsQuery.getBranchOrder(filterFol);
                            tabDetallePed.setItems(resBranOrdAdr);
                            break;
                        default:
                            showAlert("Advertencia","No ha seleccionado ningun tipo");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void clearField(ActionEvent event) {
        txtArticulo.clear();
        txtGrupo.clear();
        txtFolioPed.clear();
        cbbType.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        cbbSucursales.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        tabDetallePed.getItems().clear();
        tabEstadisticaArt.getItems().clear();
    }
    private void setCheckBoxState(){
        if(cbxArticulo.isSelected()){
            cbxFol.setSelected(false);
            cbbType.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            txtFolioPed.clear();
            cbbType.setDisable(true);
            txtFolioPed.setDisable(true);
            tabDetallePed.setDisable(true);
        }else{
            cbbType.setDisable(false);
            txtFolioPed.setDisable(false);
            tabDetallePed.setDisable(false);
        }

        if(cbxFol.isSelected()){
            cbxArticulo.setSelected(false);
            cbxGrupo.setSelected(false);
            cbxCantidad.setSelected(false);
            txtArticulo.clear();
            txtGrupo.clear();
            cbbSucursales.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            cbxGrupo.setDisable(true);
            cbxCantidad.setDisable(true);
            txtArticulo.setDisable(true);
            txtGrupo.setDisable(true);
            cbbSucursales.setDisable(true);
        }else{
            cbxGrupo.setDisable(false);
            cbxCantidad.setDisable(false);
            txtArticulo.setDisable(false);
            txtGrupo.setDisable(false);
            cbbSucursales.setDisable(false);
        }
    }
    //Method to align text in tableview
    public static class CellPosition<T> extends TableCell<T, Object> {
        private final Pos alignment;
        public CellPosition(Pos alignment) {
            this.alignment = alignment;
        }
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item == null || empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(item.toString());
            }
            setAlignment(alignment);
        }
    }
    public static <T> Callback<TableColumn<T, Object>, TableCell<T, Object>> forTableColumn(Pos alignment) {
        return param -> new CellPosition<>(alignment);
    }// Ends method to align text in tableview
}
```

Clase Estadisticas(Modelo) Incompleto por setters y getters para la segunda tabla

```
    private String artClas;
    private String artCod;
    private String artDesc;
    private int artCant;

    public String getArtClas() {
        return artClas;
    }

    public void setArtClas(String artClas) {
        this.artClas = artClas;
    }

    public String getArtCod() {
        return artCod;
    }

    public void setArtCod(String artCod) {
        this.artCod = artCod;
    }

    public String getArtDesc() {
        return artDesc;
    }

    public void setArtDesc(String artDesc) {
        this.artDesc = artDesc;
    }

    public int getArtCant() {
        return artCant;
    }

    public void setArtCant(int artCant) {
        this.artCant = artCant;
    }

    public Estadisticas() {
    }
    public Estadisticas(String artClas, String artCod, String artDesc, int artCant) {
        this.artClas = artClas;
        this.artCod = artCod;
        this.artDesc = artDesc;
        this.artCant = artCant;
    }
}
```

Clase EstadisticasQuery

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class EstadisticasQuery {

    private Connection connection;
    public EstadisticasQuery(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    //Querys for Module Statistics
    public ObservableList<Estadisticas> getArticleStatistic() {
        ObservableList<com.savadr.HerramientaFX8.Modelo.Estadisticas> articleList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        String SQL = "SELECT\n"
                +"\tia.codigo As Articulo,\n"
                +"\talm.codigo  AS Almacenes,\n"
                +"\t(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN ve.ven_tipo_operacion_id = 5 THEN vd.cantidad ELSE 0 END))\n"
                +"\t- ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN ve.ven_tipo_operacion_id = 6 THEN vd.cantidad ELSE 0 END))) AS Ventas,\n"
                +"\tCONCAT(YEAR(ve.fecha),'-',MONTH(ve.fecha)) AS Fechas,\n"
                +"COALESCE(ROUND((SELECT ie.cantidad_existencia \n"
                +"\tFROM inv_existencia ie \n"
                +"\tWHERE ie.inv_almacen_id = ve.inv_almacen_id \n"
                +"\tAND ie.inv_articulo_id = vd.inv_articulo_id\n"
                +"\tORDER BY ie.id DESC\n"
                +"\tLIMIT 1), 0)) AS Existencias\n"
                +"FROM ven_detalle vd\n"
                +"JOIN inv_articulo ia  ON vd.inv_articulo_id = ia.id\n"
                +"JOIN ven_encabezado ve ON vd.ven_encabezado_id = ve.id\n"
                +"JOIN inv_almacen alm ON ve.inv_almacen_id = alm.id\n"
                +"WHERE ve.estatus NOT IN ('CANCELADO') \n"
                +"\tAND ve.ven_tipo_operacion_id NOT IN(1,2) \n"
                +"\tAND ve.fecha >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()), INTERVAL 5 MONTH), INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(CURDATE())) - 1 DAY)\n"
                +"\tAND ve.fecha <= LAST_DAY(CURDATE())\n"
                +"\tAND ve.inv_almacen_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)\n"
                +"\tAND ia.codigo = ?\n"
                +"GROUP BY vd.inv_articulo_id, ve.inv_almacen_id, Fechas\n"
                +"ORDER BY vd.inv_articulo_id, ve.inv_almacen_id, Fechas;";
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Estadisticas statistics = new Estadisticas();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return articleList;
    }

    public ObservableList<com.savadr.HerramientaFX8.Modelo.Estadisticas> getClientOrder(String filterFol) {
        ObservableList<com.savadr.HerramientaFX8.Modelo.Estadisticas> clientOrderList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        String SQL ="SELECT\n"
                +"\tic.codigo_completo As Clasificacion,\n"
                +"\tia.codigo As Articulo,\n"
                +"\tia.descripcion As Descripcion,\n"
                +"\tROUND(vd.cantidad,0) As Cantidad\n"
                +"FROM ven_detalle vd\n"
                +"JOIN inv_articulo ia ON vd.inv_articulo_id = ia.id\n"
                +"JOIN inv_clasificacion ic ON ia.inv_clasificacion_id = ic.id\n"
                +"JOIN ven_encabezado ve ON vd.ven_encabezado_id = ve.id\n"
                +"WHERE ve.estatus NOT IN ('CANCELADO') \n"
                +"\tAND ve.ven_tipo_operacion_id IN(1,2)\n"
                +"\tAND ve.folio = ?\n"
                +"GROUP BY Clasificacion,Articulo\n"
                +"ORDER BY Clasificacion, Articulo;";
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
            ps.setString(1, filterFol);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Estadisticas statistics = new Estadisticas();
                statistics.setArtClas(rs.getString("Clasificacion"));
                statistics.setArtCod(rs.getString("Articulo"));
                statistics.setArtDesc(rs.getString("Descripcion"));
                statistics.setArtCant(rs.getInt("Cantidad"));
                clientOrderList.add(statistics);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return clientOrderList;
    }

    public ObservableList<com.savadr.HerramientaFX8.Modelo.Estadisticas> getPurchaseOrder(String filterFol) {
        ObservableList<com.savadr.HerramientaFX8.Modelo.Estadisticas> purchaseOrderList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        String SQL = "SELECT\n"
                +"\tic.codigo_completo As Clasificacion,\n"
                +"\tia.codigo As Articulo,\n"
                +"    ia.descripcion As Descripcion,\n"
                +"\tROUND(cd.cantidad) as Cantidad\n"
                +"FROM com_detalle cd\n"
                +"JOIN inv_articulo ia ON cd.inv_articulo_id = ia.id\n"
                +"JOIN inv_clasificacion ic ON ia.inv_clasificacion_id = ic.id\n"
                +"JOIN com_encabezado ce ON cd.com_encabezado_id = ce.id\n"
                +"WHERE ce.estatus NOT IN ('CANCELADO')\n"
                +"\tAND ce.com_tipo_operacion_id in (3)\n"
                +"\tAND ce.folio = ?\n"
                +"GROUP BY Clasificacion,Articulo\n"
                +"ORDER BY Clasificacion, Articulo;";
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
            ps.setString(1, filterFol);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Estadisticas statistics = new Estadisticas();
                statistics.setArtClas(rs.getString("Clasificacion"));
                statistics.setArtCod(rs.getString("Articulo"));
                statistics.setArtDesc(rs.getString("Descripcion"));
                statistics.setArtCant(rs.getInt("Cantidad"));
                purchaseOrderList.add(statistics);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return purchaseOrderList;
    }

    public ObservableList<com.savadr.HerramientaFX8.Modelo.Estadisticas> getBranchOrder(String filterFol) {
        ObservableList<com.savadr.HerramientaFX8.Modelo.Estadisticas> branchOrderList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        String SQL = "SELECT\n"
                +"\tic.codigo_completo As Clasificacion,\n"
                +"\tia.codigo As Articulo,\n"
                +"    ia.descripcion As Descripcion,\n"
                +"\tROUND(ipd.cantidad,0) As Cantidad\n"
                +"FROM inv_pedido_detalle ipd\n"
                +"JOIN inv_articulo ia ON ipd.inv_articulo_id = ia.id\n"
                +"JOIN inv_clasificacion ic ON ia.inv_clasificacion_id = ic.id\n"
                +"JOIN inv_pedido_encabezado ipe ON ipd.inv_pedido_encabezado_id = ipe.id\n"
                +"WHERE ipe.estatus NOT IN ('CANCELADO') \n"
                +"\tAND ipe.folio = ?\n"
                +"GROUP BY Clasificacion,Articulo\n"
                +"ORDER BY Clasificacion, Articulo;";
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
            ps.setString(1, filterFol);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Estadisticas statistics = new Estadisticas();
                statistics.setArtClas(rs.getString("Clasificacion"));
                statistics.setArtCod(rs.getString("Articulo"));
                statistics.setArtDesc(rs.getString("Descripcion"));
                statistics.setArtCant(rs.getInt("Cantidad"));
                branchOrderList.add(statistics);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return branchOrderList;
    }
}
```

si alguien me puede ayudar se los agradeceria ya que estoy atorado con esto, sea el metodo que me sugieran estaria bien.

[image: Foto Interfaz Modulo Estadisticas]